# POST data send and change URL to the same

Tags: php, javascript, bookmarklet, url-shortener, xmlhttprequest

I have a URL shortening service, Which I have made in PHP. It receives the URL to shorten via POST method via the form on the main page. I want to create a Bookmarklet for this service.

It should be like as one clicks it (it stays on the bookmark bar), it takes the current url and POST send it to the http://*sitelocation*/create.php and change the location to the same (as the user can see the resulting short url) **OR** displays the Shortened URL as a alert with a textbox that can be edited (so that user can copy from it).

How to do this?? It would be great to do this with XHR (preferred).

**I don't want to edit my PHP script. But I can if it is really important**

What I have tried: I just got a JavaScript (from the web) for performing a XHR request but it did not work. I have tried more than 5 Scripts but all of them just fails.

Comment: This question is about coding related. It would be better, if you have posted in **Stack Overflow** for the best answers.

Comment: @Siva Questions can always be migrated. You don't need to encourage people to post them again :)

Comment: @slhck: Yes, you are right. Actually what happened is, first i posted the comment then I got thought that I can flag for migration and done it. But in the mean while, I missed to delete the comment. Thanks for suggestion my friend.

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Keep in mind that SO isn't a place for "do this for me" requests. Oh wait, was this question inactive for about 1 week and just got moved here? Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to embed a hidden form in the current page where the action is your service and the input is window.location, then submit the form.